# how to grep from a file with two known and unknown strings in unix?

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to grep the lines containing two strings. The first string is "ulist" and the second string can have anything in prefix, but should end with string "path". Only those lines need to be grepped, which contain both of the strings.

I have tried using the below grep condition-

```
agrep -w "ulist;path" // AND between both patterns as both are required in order to grep a line
```

This command is almost grepping everything that I want but then it does not get those lines, which contain "ulist" and "sipath"(ending with string path but still not grepped). I need to grep all lines that contain "ulist" and "*path" (there can be anything before path). But, these both are required (AND between these two patterns).

Can anybody suggest the right regex pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if first should come before the second

```
$ grep '\bulist\b.*path\b' file
```

word boundaries to specify words appear not as substrings.

Comment: I was able to get what I wanted using this grep command-@karakfa

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -w ".*ulist.*path$" myfile.txt
```

By ending in a `$`, you ensure the string 'path' is at the end of the line.